# Passing multiple arguments to pool.map using class function

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to thread as described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28463266/3899919), and also pass multiple arguments in Python 2.7 through a work-around described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5443941/1893275).

Right now I have something like this, a function that is part of class `pair_scraper`:

```
def pool_threading(self):
        pool = ThreadPool(4)
        for username in self.username_list:
            master_list = pool.map(self.length_scraper2,
                itertools.izip(username*len(self.repo_list),
                itertools.repeat(self.repo_list)))

def length_scraper2(self, username, repo):
    #code
```

However, when I run my code I get the error:

```
TypeError: length_scraper2() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Which seems to be because it wants `self` passed as an argument, which is nonsensical given I'm using a class function within the class. Thoughts on how to fix?

Comment: no, that's because you're passing only 1 argument.

Comment: ... I am? How would I reformat to give arguments as intended?

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.izip(username*len(self.repo_list),itertools.repeat(self.repo_list))` yields a `tuple`.

You need to pass 2 arguments explicitly to your method (`self` is implicitly passed because it's a non-static method), but you only pass 1 tuple explicitly, plus the implicit `self` which makes 2 arguments, hence the confusing error message.

You have to use `*` to pass your tuple as 2 separate arguments, like this:

```
master_list = pool.map(self.length_scraper2,
     *itertools.izip(username*len(self.repo_list),itertools.repeat(self.repo_list)))
```

simple test using the classical `map` on a simple function:

```
def function(b,c):
    return (b,c)

print(list(map(function,zip([1,2],[4,5]))))
```

error:

```
  print(list(map(function,zip([1,2],[4,5]))))
 TypeError: function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'
```

now adding single asterisk to expand args:

```
print(list(map(function,*zip([1,2],[4,5]))))
```

works:

```
[(1, 2), (4, 5)]
```

same goes for class method:

```
class Foo:
    def function(self,b,c):
        return (b,c)

f = Foo()

print(list(map(f.function,*zip([1,2],[4,5]))))
```