# Why can't python map larger lists?

Tags: python-2.7

I am using python 2.7.

This code works:

```
def function(b,c):
    return (b,c)

print(list(map(function,*zip([1]*2,[4]*2))))
```

However, this doesn't:

```
def function(b,c):
    return (b,c)

print(list(map(function,*zip([1]*20,[4]*20))))
```

What can be done to make the second snippet work?

Comment: At some point you're trying to put too much stuff in memory. Perhaps you could use an iterator, or a library designed for handling large arrays, or ...? What are you *actually* trying to achieve, contrived example notwithstanding?

Comment: Trying to thread. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729592/passing-multiple-arguments-to-pool-map-using-class-function

Comment: How exactly is this related to threading, or to that example?

Comment: Superfluous `*zip()`.  Try `print(list(map(function,[1]*20,[4]*20)))`

Comment: Trying to figure out the best way to pass the arguments into `pool.map(func, args)`

Answer (score 1):

You've gotten mixed up about what `*zip([1]*20,[4]*20)` does. It looks like you're trying to perform the following calls:

```
function(1, 4)
function(1, 4)
... [20 calls]
```

but that's not what you're actually doing. Your code actually tries to perform the following calls:

```
function(1, 1, 1, ... [20 1s])
function(4, 4, 4, ... [20 4s])
```

Your options are to stop using `*` and `zip`, change how `function` takes arguments, or use [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap):

```
def function(b, c):
    ...

print(list(map(function, [1]*20, [4]*20)))
```

or

```
def function(x):
    b, c = x
    ...

print(list(map(function, zip([1]*20, [4]*20))))
```

or

```
import itertools

def function(b, c):
    ...

print(list(itertools.starmap(function, zip([1]*20, [4]*20))))
```